# Correlated Equilibrium 3x3 matrix - that does not respond to NE

Tags: game-theory

I need to find a correlated equilibrium in the following game (link)

[3-3matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxgBj.png)

I understand that I have to create some signals to the various situations. But I am not sure how. And how do I calculate the payoff?

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks Emilie

Comment: try pasting the matrix as opposed to linking to it which can go missing